# Can I infer any information about the correlation between the following two variables?

Tags: inequality, correlation

Consider the following bounded variable $m_1$:

$a<m_1<x$

and the following bounded variable $m_2$:

$x<m_2<b$

where $a,b,x, m_1$ and $m_2$ are all real and positive.

Consider the function

$y=\frac{m_1}{m_2}$

Is there any way to do any inferences about the correlation between $x$ and $y$?

Thank you

Comment: What are the random variables ? What are the unknowns ? What are known parameters ? Do you mean correlation in the probabilistic or statistical sense, or just "informally".

Comment: $m_1$ and $m_2$ are unkowns. $x$ and $y$ are known. Nothing here is random and what I'm curious about is a potential "informal" relationship that I cannot see but that I know it is there ($x$ and $y$ are two different performance predictors whose formulae are not shown here, but that lead to results hugely correlated). The exact relation between $a$ and $x$ is unknown, although if $a$ increases $x$  increases. The exact relation between $b$ and $x$ is unknown, although if $b$ increases $x$  increases.

Comment: Hem, are $a$ and $b$ known or unknown ?

Comment: they are known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two given inequations imply
$$\frac ab<y<1.$$

If you make a plot with the hidden variables $m_2,m_1$ for the axis, and draw a line from the origin, the slope is $y$. The locus of $(m_2,m_1)$ is a rectangle delimited by the verticals at $x$ and $b$, and the horizontals at $a$ and $x$. This rectangle is inscribed in the triangle defined by $a$, $b$ and the first bissector.

For a given $x$, the point can be anywhere in the rectangle and the slope can cover the full range $\left[\dfrac ab,1\right]$.

So without more constraints, $x$ and $y$ are *completely independent*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yves. That's a really cool visualization of the problem